# HTML5 Game Dev - Scaling HTML + Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webkit

I'm developing a game in both CSS and Canvas. UI is being developed in CSS as it makes things a lot quicker.

I would like to develop for either: 1366x768 or 1920x1080.

---

Canvas seems easy to scale as apparently all that is needed is (simple example):

HTML

```
<canvas width=1366 height=768>
```

CSS

```
canvas{ width:100%; height:100%; }
```

But how would I go on about scaling the whole page up and down? The CSS contains textures and other assets which I would like to scale with the canvas.

---

Solution I've found so far is:

CSS

```
-webkit-transform: scale(resolutionRatio, resolutionRatio)
```

where `resolutionRatio = newResolution / 1366`

But I don't fully trust this as I'm pretty sure it's not the same as `width: 100%` and have no idea if it behaves the same as the canvas scaling.

---

Would you recommend anything in particular? Am I going completely off course?

Hope someone can help. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are already using width and height 100% on the canvas so it and everything in it will be scaled with the page (and unfortunately also give less quality and performance).

The best way to scale, as canvas do not take %-values itself, is to calculate the actual width and height in pixels (and remove any CSS scaling):

```
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

This you can call on the `window`'s `resize` event and have a redraw function ready when that happen to redraw everything in scale. A bit more work, but much better result (and performance).

If you in addition set the canvas as `position: fixed` you'll get a little boost on the update of the page as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. :) Any idea how I would go on about the CSS/HTML? So that it would scale alongside the canvas?

Comment: @RadiantHex I depends on the actual layout. Perhaps you could show a rough sketch of what you want to achieve. But in general: you can bound elements to borders (top/bottom/left/right), percentage or adjust using JavaScript.